# How can I win my Supervisor's trust to do some big work?

Tags: work-environment, career-development, manager

Right now, I am interning as a Junior Developer at this big company along with another student who is from an University. Problem is, I have been feeling that he's been differentiating (or neglecting) me for doing any substantial work, for example he helped the other guy in redesigning a whole module whereas he always gives me small tasks. The other guy is a 3rd semester university student whereas I will be a college graduate after April.

My Supervisor seems to be reluctant, I think I know why. He once gave me something that took me 3 weeks to complete, (I don't know why since I know pretty well about my stuff) after that he has not been able to trust me over some substantial work. How can I win his confidence back since I really want to make a good impression on him before leaving the company?

Comment: I actually talked to him quite a few times but he still doesn't trust me, may be I should talk once more.

Comment: Well, he once mentioned that he had high expectations from me & I think I was not able to meet those expectations.

Comment: Actually to be honest, I never asked him that just because I never got a moment alone with him.

Comment: "Well, he once mentioned that he had high expectations from me & I think I was not able to meet those expectations" - was this brought to your attention at the time/discussed as you possibly didn't meet these expectations over a period of time? Do you have performance reviews or one-on-one catchups with your supervisor?

Comment: Ask for a brief meeting in his office then.

Comment: I absolutely agree with Joe that you need to ask the individual, but "He once gave me something that took me 3 weeks to complete, (I don't know why)" is worrying on two counts. Firstly the problem that you took 3 weeks. Secondly the bigger problem, that you don't know why. Being able to trust someone doesn't mean believing that they'll always deliver on time (pretty much nobody does). It means believing that they'll behave appropriately when something goes wrong. It might be the lack of trust is that your supervisor feels you didn't learn any lessons, so be prepared to revisit that incident.

Answer (score 7):

You can win your supervisor's trust by delivering results. Complete your assignments on time and in scope.  You can build trust faster by delivering results early and at higher quality than needed.  (If there's a choice between early and higher quality than needed, choose early.)

Discussion with your supervisor may clarify if there is some additional issue. But:

“You can't talk your way out of a problem you behaved your way into!” - Stephen R. Covey

You seem to have behaved your way into a lack of trust by delivering late.  Behave your way out of that by delivering early.

Comment: I would say higher quality over early if the quality is particularly important or apparent

Answer (score 5):

**Step one**, set up a meeting to discuss the issue with him. Find out exactly what you need to do in order to get that trust. Be prepared for a really uncomfortable conversation and do not end it until you have some concrete steps you can take. Do not argue his perceptions (there is close to a zero percent change that arguing at this point would help you), hear them out respectfully.  If you're undercertain of any steps, ask for clarification and repeat what you think you heard in your own words, so you're sure of the expectations.

**Step two**, do a really good job at the small tasks you are given. Meet the deadlines with a high quality product. If there are problems,  bring them up as soon as you can (one of the worst things you can do is blow a deadline on a project where you never mentioned a delay before the deadline was passed.) It is better to go to the boss with a possible solution to a problem even if you don't have the authority to make the change yourself. Bosses don't like to have problems dumped on them with no thought by the subordinate as to what to do to fix the problem.

**Step three.** He is likely to tell you some things about what to do to fix the problem. Do them. Do them whether you agree with them or not. Right now you have to change his impression of you and that means that you can't argue with what he thinks.  Your behavior has to show that you accepted the criticism, changed your behavior, and fixed the problems.